# Show android camera preview on half screen in application

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an application in which user sees its own camera preview in half screen and other half screen is a static picture
i used intent but it will show preview in fullscreen.
is there any way possible to do it?

Comment: Using fragment will be use full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 fragments to populate your UI, each taking half the screen - apply a surface view to the bottom one and use that to display real time camera data - and use the other fragment how you want.

Quick anaswer because i am at work :)

Comment: Thankyou!
if i implement fragments , can i send the image data in real time between these two fragments?
what i want to do is show half screen fragment with my camera preview and other half with another picture and then capture fullscreen picture

Comment: @Nisa Anwaar Can't you treat them independently and do a screen grab? if you need to communicate between fragments use callbacks. you done this before? I guess i do not fully understand your requirments

Comment: i want half my screen to show my camera preview
then apply image processing algorithm on my camera preview frame data 
and when user clicks "capture" application merges my preview with other half image
I cant use screen grab because it will effect qulaity

Comment: @Nisa Anwaar, so you want a live camera feed in one fragment, and a preview of what the finished picture will look like after your pocessing in the other fragment which updates real time?

Comment: yes ,  it will merge both halves in the end when capture is clicked.

Comment: @NisaAnwaar My question is why bother sending data real-time why not have a camera instance in both - one with processing one without, surely this is faster?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceView" android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main.java**:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

preview = new Preview(this, (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
preview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout)).addView(preview);
```

**Preview.java**:

```
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera mCamera;

    Preview(Context context, SurfaceView sv) {
        super(context);
        mSurfaceView = sv;
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();

            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null)
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;
            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }

            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                        (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2, width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e("AWAISSOOMRO_TAG", "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera != null) mCamera.stopPreview();
    }


    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;
        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            requestLayout();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }
}
```

`SOURCE: https://github.com/josnidhin/Android-Camera-Example`